# Building first React component/app, issues with axios returning duplicate responses

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

here is my react component

```
import './App.css';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faQuoteLeft } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { faTwitter } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons';
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const quoteIcon = <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faQuoteLeft} />;
const twitterIcon = <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTwitter} />;


class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    quote: ''
  };
  componentDidMount(){
    this.fetchQuote();
  }

  fetchQuote = () => {
    axios.get("https://api.quotable.io/random")
    .then((response)=>{
      const {quote} = response.data.content;

      this.setState({ quote });
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }
  
  render() {
    const { quote } = this.state;
    return (
      <div id='wrapper'>
        <div id='quote-box'>
          <div className='quote-text'>
            <div id='quoteIcon'>{quoteIcon}</div><span id='text'>{this.state.quote}</span>
          </div>
          <div className='quote-author'>-<span id='author'></span></div>
  
          <div className='buttons'>
            <a href="link" className='button' id='tweet-quote'>{twitterIcon}</a>
            <button className='button' id='new-quote' onClick={this.fetchQuote}>New quote</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I'm not able to get the quote to render on the screen. I tried to console.log what was happening after I get my response with axios, and for some reason I keep getting two calls. I get two different quotes logged. I'm not sure if that's why I'm having issues with getting it rendered.

I've tried using other methods like fetch and I still get duplicate responses. I'm thinking it's my componentDidMount() mounting multiple times for some reason? but I don't know why it would do that. But I need it to load my function when the component mounts so I don't want to not use it. When I do get rid of it, it obviously doesn't run my function but I believe it still is getting double responses.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem is while you are destructuring inside `fetchQuote` function

Instead of this >
`const {quote}=response.data.current`

you can replace it with >
`const quote=response.data.current`

There is nothing like quote exist in the `response.data.current`
That's why your quote is not getting set.

Answer (score 1):

your data is:
**response.data**
`{_id: "UBum36vM5", tags: Array(1), content: "Remember that a gesture of friendship, no matter how small, is always appreciated.", author: "H. Jackson Brown Jr.", authorSlug: "h-jackson-brown-jr"…}`

But you (Destructuring "quote") what does not exist.

`const {quote} = response.data.content; const quote = response.data.content;`

Answer (score 0):

While its still logging two quotes for some reason, I think the issue with it not rendering to the screen was how I was setting the state.

I did

```
this.setState({
  quote: response.data.content
});
```